# jQuery UI Datepicker and select box dilemma

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have experimented with the datepicker in the jQuery UI and can get it working with select boxes but only when there is a day, month and year select box (http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerIntoSelects.html).

What I need is to have a day and a month-year box like the one that can be seen here...(http://www.bookassist.com/hotels/index.jsp?source=org)

Anyone out there know if this can be done? Totally hit a brick wall.

Comment: Post what you've already done on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and share the link. This way everyone can help you better.

Comment: Can't you just use an "onselect" handler to set your dropdown elements appropriately when a date is picked?

Comment: Here is the code on jsFiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/aggYd/ I tried ace's solution below, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to modify this part from http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerIntoSelects.html

Change this part, the initialization of the datePicker,

```
$(function()
{

    // initialise the "Select date" link
    $('#date-pick')
        .datePicker(
            // associate the link with a date picker
            {
                createButton:false,
                startDate:'01/01/2005',
                endDate:'31/12/2010'
            }
```

to this, by adding the months array and updating the endDate.

```
$(function()
{
    var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

    // initialise the "Select date" link
    $('#date-pick')
        .datePicker(
            // associate the link with a date picker
            {
                createButton:false,
                startDate:'01/01/2005',
                endDate:'31/12/2015'
            }
```

Then, change the function that updates the 3 selects (d,m,y)

```
var updateSelects = function (selectedDate)
{
    var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    $('#d option[value=' + selectedDate.getDate() + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#m option[value=' + (selectedDate.getMonth()+1) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#y option[value=' + (selectedDate.getFullYear()) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

to just (d,m) with the month specified in this format "August 2011".

```
var updateSelects = function (selectedDate)
{
    var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    $('#d option[value=' + selectedDate.getDate() + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#m option[value=' + (months[selectedDate.getMonth()]) + ' ' +  (selectedDate.getFullYear()) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Then change the function that updates the picker when changing the selects from this

```
// listen for when the selects are changed and update the picker
$('#d, #m, #y')
    .bind(
        'change',
        function()
        {
            var d = new Date(
                        $('#y').val(),
                        $('#m').val()-1,
                        $('#d').val()
                    );
            $('#date-pick').dpSetSelected(d.asString());
        }
    );
```

Into this, (EDIT: I mistakenly swapped the year value and day value in my previous answer.)

```
// listen for when the selects are changed and update the picker
$('#d, #m')
    .bind(
        'change',
        function()
        {
            var d = new Date(
                        $('#m').val().split(" ")[1],
                        months.indexOf($('#m').val().split(" ")[0]),
                        $('#d').val()
                    );
            $('#date-pick').dpSetSelected(d.asString());
        }
    );
```

This is the http://jsfiddle.net/2Nedr/1/ that does just that.
Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks ace but it didn't work. I have added a link to jsFiddle in the first post above.

Comment: Yes it didn't work too when I checked it. It seems the code has a problem when setting to most recent date. I'll update my answer in a while.

Comment: Here's a working code. http://jsfiddle.net/2Nedr/
I'm working out on the error his code has, notice that it doesn't have the year 2011 in his example, try adding 2011 and 2012 and his code will not work.

Comment: My bad. There was an endDate config. I will be updating my answer in a while.

Comment: Thanks for the help ace. I need to remove the Year select box an have the month and year in the one select box eg Aug-2011,Oct-2012 etc

Comment: Ah, do you have it working already? You just need to change the `$('#m').val().split(" ")[1]` to `$('#m').val().split("-")[1]` and `months.indexOf($('#m').val().split(" ")[0])` to `months.indexOf($('#m').val().split("-")[0])` and also change the Months Array from `['January','February',...]` to `['Jan','Feb',...]`